# pyspark RowMatrix failes: DataFrame must have a single vector type column

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a table of a string column and a list column:

```
app        vector
facebook   [1,2,3]
instagram  [4,5,6]
whatsapp   [7,8,9]
```

I want to calculate the cosine similarity between every 2 apps so I am trying to convert
the vector column to a RowMatrix:

```
mat = RowMatrix(app_vectors_df.select("vector"))
cosine_similarities = mat.columnSimilarities()
```

However I keep getting this error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: DataFrame must have a single vector type column
```

If I try converting the list to a dense vector I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert type <class 'pyspark.ml.linalg.DenseVector'> into Vector
```

I'm not sure how to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the method.  Try converting to an RDD instead:

For Sparse Vectors:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors    
mat = RowMatrix(app_vectors_df.select("vector").rdd.map (lambda x: Vectors.sparse(x[0].size, x[0].indices, x[0].values)))
```

For Dense Vectors:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
mat = RowMatrix(app_vectors_df.select("vector").rdd.map (lambda x: Vectors.dense(x[0].toArray())
```